# I search for replacement of Xethron/migrations-generator in laravel 6,7

Tags: laravel

I try to move my  laravel 5.8 to 6x, 7x branch.

I found that the package I periodically use
https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator
is not supported for 6, 7 branches.

Has it any replacement ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their are multiple issues about Laravel 6+ compatibility:

[Laravel 6.0 Compatibility](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator/issues/191)

[Laravel 7 support](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator/issues/200)

You can use one of these packages as a replacement:

[oscarafdev/migrations-generator](https://github.com/oscarafdev/migrations-generator)

[kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator](https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator)